# mdadm RAID5 inactive and drive missing

Tags: linux, mdadm, raid5

I have a raid5 set up with mdadm and had to replace one broken hard drive.
It worked for a while, but for some reason, became inactive after a couple of weeks.

I'm pretty sure that the missing drive `/dev/sdb` is also the one I replaced:

```
# sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 3

              Name : REMOTENAME:0  (local to host REMOTENAME)
              UUID : 59f98bf3:274707c2:2d79bc60:f0217294
            Events : 212054

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
       -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
       -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
```

Next, `/proc/mdstat` contains:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdc[1](S) sde[4](S) sdd[2](S)
      23441683464 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
```

The hard drive state seems to be ok, as no errors are with `smartctl` for `/dev/sdb`.

Lastly, `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb` yields:

```
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you all for your comments! I'm actually not the one who setup that RAID, more like the lucky one inheriting the responsibility for it. I'll gladly take your advicde for the next setup :)

You're actually right, that it says raid0 now. I found a textfile where I saved the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` which might be insightful?

```
# sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Jul 24 13:22:48 2018
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 23441682432 (22355.73 GiB 24004.28 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 7813894144 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent
     Intent Bitmap : Internal
       Update Time : Mon Sep  4 07:36:57 2023
             State : clean, checking
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0
            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K
Consistency Policy : bitmap
      Check Status : 77% complete
              Name : REMOTENAME:0  (local to host REMOTENAME)
              UUID : 59f98bf3:274707c2:2d79bc60:f0217294
            Events : 212051
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       5       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       4       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
```

Possibly related, I found some differences between the hard drive `/dev/sdb` and the other ones of the raid:

```
# sudo lshw -class disk
...
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD80EFZZ-68B
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 0A81
       serial: ---
       size: 7452GiB (8001GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=a931e3f0-c80c-447b-b4f6-e3a06b9b51a7 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD80EFZX-68U
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdc
       version: 0A83
       serial: ---
       size: 7452GiB (8001GB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
...
```

Previously, there was no `partitioned` info given on the old drive `/dev/sdb`:

```
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD80EFZX-68U
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 0A83
       serial: ---
       size: 7452GiB (8001GB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

**EDIT2:**

As the array was inactive, I reactivated it successfully using `sudo mdadm --run /dev/md0`. You are right, that somehow, potentially after a reboot, `/dev/sdb` dropped out of the array/was removed?...

```
# sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Jul 24 13:22:48 2018
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 23441682432 (22355.73 GiB 24004.28 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 7813894144 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Nov  2 14:10:31 2023
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : REMOTENAME:0  (local to host REMOTENAME)
              UUID : 59f98bf3:274707c2:2d79bc60:f0217294
            Events : 212077

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       4       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
```

My question now would be: Should I re-format the disk on `/dev/sdb` before adding it to the array again?

And a bonus question, as it has been pointed out: Can you savely transform an existing raid5 into, e.g. raid1 or raid6?

Comment: That `mdadm --examine/dev/sdb` really looks like sdb was never actually added to the array. Perhaps try re-adding it?

Comment: Try really hard not to use R5, it's dangerous and has been effectively dead for well over a decade, use R1/10 or R6/60 instead - we get a LOT of R5 users come here to ask for help getting their data back sadly.

Comment: You said raid5, but your output says raid0?

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comments! I've added more information under EDIT

Comment: @tsc_chazz: Thank you! I've tried that before with `sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb`, which returned in the return `mdadm: Cannot get array info for /dev/md0`

Comment: Given that a disk failed after less than one year, and there's no monitoring, add multiple hot spares, and code to check that all the disks are present and functional, and send an alert if not. https://serverfault.com/questions/351240/convert-linux-software-raid-from-raid5-to-raid6